# Instrumenting JavaScript calls in Google V8

Tags: javascript, v8, instrumentation

I am attempting to instrument JavaScript function calls in two Google V8-backed environments (Thug and a JS forced execution engine). Basically, when I run an externally-provided HTML file with JavaScript I would like to get one line per API call with: 
   - the call name
   - arguments sent to the call (if there are any)

I can currently do this for JavaScript Global methods (e.g. - eval(), decode(), encode()) and various DOM-level methods (e.g. - document.createElement()) by doing stuff like this:

```
var old_eval = eval;
function new_eval(foo0)
{
    alert("INSTRUMENTATION: eval," + foo0);
    return old_eval(foo0);
}
eval = new_eval;
```

I am able to define methods like this in my own JavaScript file and then incorporate this file into the V8 runtime.

This works well enough for global functions, but doesn't help for object member access or access to object-level methods (e.g. - somestring.indexOf()).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by API call? There is a V8 bindings API (which I think is not what you want). I presume you're referring to JavaScript builtin functions?

Comment: Yes, I mean JavaScript built-in functions. I'm trying to capture information from a dynamic execution environment for use in a classifier, but haven't found a way to capture call and argument information EXCEPT in the case of globally-defined functions like eval() or with respect to methods on types like 'document' and 'location'.

Answer (score 1):

Logging all function Events in V8 is not directly supported.
You have two options:

1. Patch all known functions / getters/setters upfront (requires full knowledge of your code base)
2. Patch V8 to log all function calls

Option 2 is certainly going to be more work. There is partial support for logging the first execution of a function with `--log-function-events` but it does not include API callbacks (e.g. DOM accessors and certain builtin functions).

Correctly supporting logging **all** function calls is a non-trivial task in V8 and would require patching various places in the code-base.